# Checking Black Pixels in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an image (5x5)pixels with 3 values which value 0, 128, and 255.

I want to check the pixels of the index (1,1) to (1,5).

If there is pixel value 0 (black), then the pixels of the index (1,1) to (1,5) is changed to 128 (gray), if none, then the pixels are changed to 255 (white).

I want to do these steps again, checking of the index (2,1) to (2,5), (3,1) to (3,5), through to the bottom.

from the above problems, I get a solution like this:

mask = repmat(any(I == 0,2),5,1);

I(mask) = 128;

I(~mask) = 255;

but if I want to check...

If there are pixels value 0 (black) >3, then the pixels of the index (1,1) to (1,5) is changed to 128 (gray), if there are pixels value 0 (black) <=3 or no black pixel, then the pixels are changed to 255 (white).

what's the solution?

Thank You

Regards, Wahyu

Comment: If you want more people looking at your question, consider adding more tags, but choose ones relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try computing the histogram of each row of the matrix, then read the histogram value for zero:

```
x = m[1,:];
[counts, bins] = hist(x, unique(x));
[diff, pos] = min(abs(bins - 0));  % replace zero with the value you want to search for
if counts(pos) > 3
    z = 128
else
    z = 255
end
m[1,:] = z * ones(1, size(m)(2));
```

I was inspired for this solution by [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1VV1U8/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-1VV1U8).